# Div inside another div with some padding

Tags: html, css

I am planning to place a div inside another div with padding . but i face some problem top position remains same. how can i solve this issue

```css
<style type="text/css">
#outdiv
{
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 630px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: #1C4675;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position:relative;
}

#outdiv_inner
{   
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    width: 1090px;
    height: 620px;
   
    background: #E8E8E8;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<html>
<div id="outdiv">
    <div id="outdiv_inner"></div>
</div>
  </html>
```

Comment: There's no `padding` on your css. Maybe confusing `padding` with `margin`. Two veeery different things...

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the blue div to appear behind the gray one, I believe you are really confusing `padding` with `margin`. Set a padding, with the same values on the `#outdiv`:

```css
#outdiv
{
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
   padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 630px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: #1C4675;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position:relative;
}

#outdiv_inner
{   
    width: 1090px;
    height: 620px;
    background: #E8E8E8;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<html>
<div id="outdiv">
    <div id="outdiv_inner"></div>
</div>
  </html>
```

Of course, if that was the case, you could simply use a blue "border" on the inner div:

```css
#outdiv
{
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
   padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 630px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: #1C4675;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position:relative;
}

#outdiv_inner
{   
    width: 1090px;
    height: 620px;
    background: #E8E8E8;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
   border-top: 10px solid #1C4675;
   border-bottom: 10px solid #1C4675;
   border-left: 5px solid #1C4675;
   border-right: 5px solid #1C4675;
}
```

```html
<div id="outdiv_inner"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
#outdiv
{
    padding: 5px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 630px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: #1C4675;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position:relative;
}

#outdiv_inner
{   
    width: 1090px;
    height: 620px;
    background: #E8E8E8;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outdiv">
    <div id="outdiv_inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe6xb3mq/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `#outdiv`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0d7njs2j/)**

Answer (score 0):

## outdiv_inner.height + #outdiv_inner.margin-top + #outdiv_inner.margin-bottom > #outdiv.height

try this:

```
#outdiv_inner
{   
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    width: 1090px;
    height: 610px;
   display:block;
    background: #E8E8E8;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```